# Getting two values for Docker container list when filtered

Tags: docker

This is a bit strange.

I loaded two docker images in my system, say image1 and image2.

I then created the following containers:

- containerA with image1
- containerB with image2

When I run the command **docker ps -a --filter "name=containerA" --format "{{.Status}}"**, I get two values (Example: **Up 11 minutes** and **Up 16 minutes**)

If I run the same command but for containerB, I get only one value. So:
**docker ps -a --filter "name=containerB" --format "{{.Status}}"** gives me **Up 16 minutes**

So, I'm getting the status of both containers even tough the containerA has just one image.

Is this a bug? Am I filtering wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one container name is a substring of another, you'll see this behavior.

[From the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering):

> The name filter matches on all or part of a container’s name.

So if you do a:

```
docker ps -a --filter "name=container5" --format "{{.Status}}"

docker ps -a --filter "name=container51" --format "{{.Status}}"
```

the first command would include container5 and container51.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Didn't saw that on the docs. So in this case I don't have any other way to get only the value for that specific name?

Comment: @zephirus Since you know the name of your container, do an inspect instead of a ps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it seems filter allows regular expressions):

```
docker ps -a --filter "name=^container5$" --format "{{.Status}}"
```

That will give only a result, not two even if container51 does exist.

Comment: Thank you, Roberto. That is a great solution!

Comment: You're welcome. Please vote if you think this is a solution